# Random link and once one is shown, I don't want it to show up again

Tags: javascript, random

I am a newbie to all this, so here is my question.
I have three different websites. What I want to do is; when people click the link, one of them is randomly chosen and shows  up.  Later when they click a button in the website, it will take them randomly to one of the other two, so the one that is already shown won't show up. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it via javascript efficiently, else in server side java in the servlet you need to handle the forward action based on random values that take you to next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do this in java, but you may be looking for a different language. PHP or JavaScript is what you want if you want to do it on a website.

```
public static void displaySite() {
     Random random = new Random();
     boolean[] passed = {false, false, false};
     String[] websites = new String[];
     //intialize website urls here


     while(true) { //Will have to use a break statement
         int website = random.nextInt(2);
         if (passed[website] == false) { //This website has not yet been shown
             System.out.println(websites[website]);
             passed[website] = true;
         }
     //Do input and possible break statement here.
     }
}
```

Just call that method every time you want to display the random sites. But every time you call it, all three websites could show again.